# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException invoking method of an external assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, remoting

I'm playing with reflection and remoting for the first time. I have an assembly present on the machine, that I have read-only access to the source code of, and I want to invoke one of its methods directly. This is my code:

```
        AppDomain NewDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain");
        try
        {
            var objectHandle = NewDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\ExistingAssembly.dll", "RemoteNamespace.RemoteClass");
            var localObject = (RemoteNamespace.ISharedInterface)objectHandle.Unwrap();
            File.Copy(localObject.StrTargetMethod(arg1),
                Path.Combine(logDir, logfile), true);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(NewDomain);
        }
```

At the first line of the `try` block, the `CreateInstanceFrom` method throws an `UnhandledException: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'RemoteNamespace.RemoteClass, RemoteNamespace, Version=1.2.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx'`.

EDIT: I'm now trying this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\ExistingAssembly.dll");
var localObject = (ISharedInterface)assembly.CreateInstance("RemoteNamespace.RemoteClass");
```

but I'm getting the same error being thrown at `assembly.CreateInstance()`. I logged `assembly.GetTypes()` to screen, so I know the assembly is loading correctly, and the class I'm after is in the printed list.

EDIT 2: Using `Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.FullName, "RemoteNamespace.RemoteClass")` worked, once I added the assembly location as a `<dependentAssembly>` block in App.config. I have no idea what the problem with `assembly.CreateInstance()` is. For reference of anyone else coming across this question, the XML needed in App.config is:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="[AssemblyNameWithoutFileExtension]" publicKeyToken="[AssemblyPublicKeyToken]" culture="neutral" />
      <codeBase version="[AssemblyVersionNumber]" href="file:///[FullAssemblyFilePath]" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```